# Laravel - Select em multiplas tabelas

Tags: sql, laravel, query

**Meu objetivo no código é**: 
- Criar uma opção de filtro para o cliente, onde ele vai ter as opções de filtrar o produto por: COR, GRUPO, CARACTERÍSTICA E MEDIDAS.

---

**Meu problema é**:
 - Criar a query que aceite que aceite array's e que aceite quando um das opções de filtro não for selecionada. Por ex: Quero só filtrar por cor, mas não pelas outras opções.

---

Código que tenho até o momento.

```
$produtos = DB::table('products')                  
              ->join('cores_produto','cores_produto.produto_id','products.id')
              ->join('grupos_produto','grupos_produto.produto_id','products.id')
              ->whereIn('cores_produto.cor_id', $c )
              ->whereIn('grupos_produto.grupo_id', $g)                  
              ->groupBy('products.id')->orderBy('products.id')
              ->select('*')
              ->toSql();
```

Retorno da query sql selecionando só a opção das cores.

```
select * from `products` inner join `cores_produto` on `cores_produto`.`produto_id` = `products`.`id` inner join `grupos_produto` on `grupos_produto`.`produto_id` = `products`.`id` where `cores_produto`.`cor_id` in (?) and 0 = 1 group by `products`.`id` order by `products`.`id` asc
```

Comment: Rapaz eu não consegui entender sua pergunta, tem como explicar de outra forma ou mais claramente ?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu vou no filtro e quero saber todos os produtos que tem a cor "Azul e Amarela", mas não seleciono nada no grupo, ele me retorna uma query vazia, pois ao invés de ele não jogar na query o que é nulo ele joga o valor 'and 0 = 1', ai vem vazia.

Comment: aonde que entraria esse valor nulo ? eu ainda não to seguro di que é seu problema.

Comment: A sua pergunta não está muito clara

Comment: @VirgilioNovic desculpa não estar sendo muito claro pessoal. Editei o post pra um melhor entendimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde adrib,

Não conheço muito de php, porém com uma pesquisa rápida na web achei uma alternativa interessante para solucionar seu problema.

Se entendi bem, o problema pode ser resumido em: "Quero gerar uma query a partir do filtro que o usuário vai preencher, e ignorar os campos que ele não preencheu", está correto?

Caso sim, você pode tentar realizar a consulta via Eloquent ORM a partir de um método `when(teste, function())`, que executa uma função se o parâmetro do teste for **TRUE**,

**Exemplo:**

```
$produtos = Produto::when(Request::input('produto'),function($query){
                        $query->where('nome_produto',Request::input('produto'));
                    })
                    ->when(Request::input('preco'),function($query){
                        $query->where('preco_produto',Request::input('preco'));
                    })
                    ->when(Request::input('categoria'), function($query){
                        $query->whereHas('categoria', function ($query) {
                            $query->where('nome_categoria',Request::input('categoria'));
                        });
                    })->get();
```

Aqui temos um código que vai checar se o campo do filtro foi preenchido, se sim, vai executar a `function($query)`, e após ter verificado todos os campos vai dar um `get()` e gerar sua Query de consulta.

Espero ter ajudado, mas caso não tenha solucionado ainda o problema dá uma pesquisada nas referências, talvez você consiga entender melhor a partir delas.

Abraços.

**- Referências:**

[Consulta com Filtro via Eloquest ORM](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-consulta-com-filtro-via-eloquent-orm-35886#584654)

[Requests & Input - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

Comment: Boa tarde meu amigo.
EXATO: "Quero gerar uma query a partir do filtro que o usuário vai preencher, e ignorar os campos que ele não preencheu"

As vezes nos faltam palavras. Vou fazer esse teste agora e após compartilhar os resultados.
Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

## Solução

---

Para conseguir ajudar quem estiver com o mesmo problema que eu, marquei a resposta do nosso amigo @H.Lima acima como a solução que me fez pensar e resolver o problema. 
Abaixo vou descrever como ficou meu código e o que precisei entender.

```
$produtos = Produto::when(Request::input('cores'), function($query){
                  $query->whereHas('relacionamentoCores', function ($query) {
                      $query->where('cores_produto.produto_id',Request::input('cores'));
                  });})->get();
```

Não estava entendendo como iria fazer o relacionamento das tabelas dentro da explicação acima citada pelo amigo, foi ai que percebi após o whereHas deveria ficar o **relacionamentoCores** que fazia parte do relacionamento entre as Models.
Sendo assim, a resposta para a pergunta

> Quero gerar uma query a partir do filtro que o usuário vai preencher, e ignorar os campos que ele não preencheu.

se encaixa perfeitamente na resposta acima.